# undefined offset error

Tags: php, html, forms, button

I want to display values retrieved from mysql in forms and in row by row format.
So i used the following code.

```
<?php 
  while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ 
?>
<tr height="30" > 
<?php $elyid = $rows1['id'] ?>
  <form action="leaveactions.php" method="post" name="viewleave">
   <td width="82"><?php echo $rows1['empid'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows1['name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows1['leavetype'];?></td>
   <td width="82"><?php echo $rows1['startdate']; ?></td>
   <td width="82"><?php echo $rows1['enddate']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows1['leavetype']; ?></td>
   <td>
     <input type="submit" name="<?php $rows1['id']; ?>" value="accept"/>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input type="submit" name="reject" value="reject"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="emplid" value="<?php echo $rows1['id'] ?>"/>
   </td>
</tr>
<?php       } ?>
```

and in leaveactions.php

```
$ii=0;
$query1 = "select * from applied_leaves where supervisorid ='".$employeeId."' and status='not approved'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error());
$num1 = mysql_numrows($result1);

while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $ii++;
  echo $_POST["$ii"];
  if(isset($_POST['$ii'])){
    echo "accepted "; echo $_POST['$ii'];
    $updateEmp = "update applied_leaves set status='".$accept."' where id='$ii' " ;
    $uresult = mysql_query($updateEmp) or die (mysql_error());
    if($uresult != null){
      echo "Assignment Added successfully<br>";
?>
      <a href="updateassignment.php">View Added Details</a>
<?php                       
    } else {
      echo "error";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

but when run i get

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1
 Notice: Undefined offset: 2
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

like that.
Please help me solving the problem.
Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**

the new code that is causing exception is

```
                     $iii=0;
                while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                {
                  $iii++;

                if(  $_POST["accpt".$iii] ) { 

                  echo "accepted "; 
                  $updateEmp = "update applied_leaves set status='".$accept."' where id='$iii' " ;
                  $uresult = mysql_query($updateEmp) or die (mysql_error());
                  if($uresult != null){
                        echo "Assignment Added successfully<br>";
                        ?>
                        <a href="updateassignment.php">View Added Details</a>
                        <?php   break;                  
                    }

                }

                }
```

Comment: Try dropping the first `echo $_POST["$ii"];` command. Assuming that's the correct line for those notices.

Comment: but by removing i dont get error, also the things need to be done when button is clicked is also not called.

Comment: I refer to the call in `leaveactions.php`. To me it looks like just a debug message. But you do it, before you actually check, whether the variable is set (which you do on the next line ...).

Comment: when i tried echo isset($_POST['$ii']) it does not display anything.so i think name is not assigned to button.

Comment: See my answer below. Furthermore at one of the echos, you had a wrong closing tag: it said just `>` instead of `?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main error lies here:

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php $rows1['id']; ?>" value="accept"/>
```

Here you do not echo `$rows1['id']`, so if you have a look in the generated code, the name should be empty.

Correct this to

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $rows1['id']; ?>" value="accept"/>
```

---

Furthermore in `leaveactions.php` you have the following code:

```
// ...
echo $_POST["$ii"];
if(isset($_POST['$ii'])){
  echo "accepted "; echo $_POST['$ii'];
// ...
```

Here you should first check, whether the variable (here it is `$_POST[$ii]` - no `"` needed) before doing the output.

As a result of the previous error, `$_POST[$ii]` is not set, thus you get the notice on the first `echo` and never enter the `if`-clause afterward.

Comment: thank you.after setting echo in name, it is working good,but when form is called by button name 2 then it is throwing error that undefined offset 1.

Comment: @krishna That's what I'm referring to the whole time and in the second block of this answer. *Remove*  the `echo $_POST[$ii]` before the `if( isset() )` clause!

Comment: i removed it previously before making your changes.but the error caused due to isset($_POST['$ii']) because it is in while loop when it comes across isset($_POST[1]) it shows error.

Comment: @krishna Can you put the (current) code somewhere and point to the line, which yields the error?

Comment: @krishna Why did you drop the `isset()`? Use this if-clause: `if(  isset($_POST["accpt".$iii]) )`

Comment: Thank you man.Since i am new to php i thought isset is not required.now it is working fine.

Comment: @krishna As you see, not using `isset()` just yields a notice, not an error. It is much cleaner style to use it, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the array position you are trying to access is empty(not available). Check whether the array position exist using [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) method.

```
if( isset( $array['position'] )
{
  //position exists
}
```

*Just don't post your code here. Paste the line which is relevant to the error. At least try commenting the line where the error occurs.*

Comment: but is calling all the buttons in form and updating all values instead of rows corresponding to that button only.